# best way of hiding div outside a parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 divs - parent and child. Child is positioned absolutely inside the parent, and can move around depending on user interaction. However, the child is bigger than the parent, and I only want the part of the child inside the parent to be visible.

A perfect example would be facebook cover photos - the actual cover photo can be quite large, but we can only see part of it, and the user can move it around. I know I can hide the outer part by placing divs on all four sides of the parent and setting the Z indexes, but I was wondering if there is a different (better) way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `overflow: hidden;` on the parent.